# Change cell reference dynamically based on last filled cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A        B        C        D         E       F       G      H
1    Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr       Jun     Jul     Aug    Sept
2   5.000    4.000    5.000    8.000     9.000   
3   $A$2:$H$2
4
```

In **Cell A3** I use the following formula to get the cell references from **Row 2**:

```
A3 ="$"&LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A2),4),1+(COLUMN(A2)>26))&"$"&ROW(A2)&":$"&LEFT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(H2),4),1+(COLUMN(H2)>26))&"$"&ROW(H2)
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, my target ist now to make the **cell reference** more dynamically. As you can see in my example there is no number yet for `Jul, Aug, Sept`. Therefore, I also want that the cell reference is not going further then `Jun` (**Cell E2**). 
 I could do this by just manually change the reference in my formula but I would prefer a solution that automatically detects the **last filled cell** and uses that cell as the last cell reference. 
In my case the last filled cell is E2 but it will change once July is over and then the last filled cell will be August (F2) and so on ...

Do you have any idea how I could solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(), 1, 1)&":"&ADDRESS(2, MATCH(1E+99, 2:2), 1, 1)
```

[image]

For the address of the last non-blank/non-zero number,

```
=ADDRESS(2, COLUMN(), 1, 1)&":"&ADDRESS(2, AGGREGATE(14, 7, COLUMN($A:$Z)/($A$2:$Z$2<>0), 1), 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works really nice. Is there also a way to modify the formula in a way so a 0 value in Aug and Sept is also detected as an empty cell?

Comment: Thanks for the additional help with the 0 value.

Comment: Do you also have an idea for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463454/change-cell-reference-dynamically-based-on-last-filled-cell-using-office-2007