# Change cell reference dynamically based on last filled cell using Office 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
    A      B        C       D        E        F         G       H       I         J
1                  Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr       May     Jun     Jul      Aug
2                 5.000    4.000    5.000    8.000     9.000     0
3                
4                $C$2:$J$2
5
6
```

In **Cell C4** I use the following formula to get the cell references from `Row 2`:

```
C4 = "$"&LEFT(ADRESS(1,COLUMN(C2),4),1+(COLUMN(C2)>26))&"$"&ROW(C2)&":$"&LEFT(ADRESS(1,COLUMN(J2),4),1+(COLUMN(J2)>26))&"$"&ROW(J2)
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, my target ist now to make the cell reference more dynamically. As you can see in my example there is either a `0` or `no number` for `Jun, Jul, Aug`. Therefore, I also want that the cell reference is not going further then May (`Cell G2`). Once there is a `number > 0` for June the cell reference should automatically go until `Cell H2` and so on ...

I tried to go with the formula from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229983/change-cell-reference-dynamically-based-on-last-filled-cell). However, since I only have `Office 2007` availalbe I cannot use a formula that contains the `AGGREGAT` function as in the answer in the link.

Is there any other solution for Office 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel 2007 (US English version) does not have the `LINKS` or `ADRESS` functions.  But an English version of the formula which will return the last address in row 2 that contains a value greater than 0:

```
= ADDRESS(2,LOOKUP(2,1/($2:$2>0),COLUMN($2:$2)))
```

In your example that formula returns `$G$2`.

Examine HELP for the LOOKUP function for an explanation of how this works (when `lookup_value` is greater than any of the items in the array being tested).

I'm not sure if you want to detect or merely hard code the first address.  To hard code, merely:

```
= "$C$2:" & ADDRESS(2,LOOKUP(2,1/($2:$2>0),COLUMN($2:$2)))
```

or perhaps some variant of:

```
= ADDRESS(2,3) & ":" & ADDRESS(2,LOOKUP(2,1/($2:$2>0),COLUMN($2:$2)))
```

Comment: Thansk Ron. Exactly what I was looking for.